# IF statement checking multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets

I would like my `IF` statement to check all rows and output a "check tips" if even one row qualifies.

Does that make sense?

```
=if(G3:I3=0, "check tips")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> ***EDIT***
>   *I think I misunderstood your question.*

The following formula will give you the desired result.

```
=IFERROR(IF((VLOOKUP(0, ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(G3:G21),MMULT(N(G3:I21),TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN(G3:I21)))),)),1,0))=0,"Check Tips"),)
```

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER

You can use the following formula:

```
=IF(SUM(G3:I3)<>0,"","Check Tips")
```

Functions used:

- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)

Comment: Have you tried the solution offered? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.